# Android: How to pass URL from one fragment to another

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I got few fragments in my app, I wanted to send the URL from the current fragment to another fragment when clicked on that url and the next fragment to open that url.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the second fragment you need to pass the URL as an argument:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("url", myUrl);
Fragmentclass fragment = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String url = getArguments().getString("url");    

}
```

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating), your fragments shouldn't directly communicate with each other. The communication should be performed through the Activity. So, the best way for me is to create Callback interface in the first fragment and cast parent Activity to it:

```
public interface Callback {
    void onUrlOpen(String url);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mCallback = ((Callback) getActivity());
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Parent activity should implement callback interface!");
    }
}
```

Implement this interface in your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment1.Callback
```

And in implementation (in MainActivity.java) call the appropriate method of Fragment2:

```
@Override
public void onUrlOpen(String url) {
    fragment2.openUrl(url);
}
```

And then you just need to call `mCallback.onUrlOpen("example.com");` in your first fragment. This will call your activity's method, and your activity's method will call appropriate method of the second fragment.

In the future you can add additional methods to your Callback interface and implement them in your Activity.